# g++ doesn't search for headers in current directory first

Tags: c++, g++

I have several headers `a.h` with the same name in the current directory and in the directory `inc`. I would like the one from the current directory to be included in `main.cpp`, but I need other header `b.h` from directory `inc`. However, GCC doesn't search for headers in the current directory first. Why?

`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>

#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;
    std::cout << FOO << std::endl;
    std::cout << BAR << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`build/a.h`

```
#define FOO 1
```

`inc/a.h`

`inc/b.h`

```
#define BAR 1
```

from `build/` directory:

```
build$ g++ -I. -I../inc ../main.cpp -o ../main
../main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
../main.cpp:10:18: error: ‘FOO’ was not declared in this scope
     std::cout << FOO << std::endl;
                  ^
```

If I remove, `inc/a.h`, everything works.

gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11)

Comment: It may be better to include explicitly: `#include <A.h>` vs. `#include <inc/A.h>`

Comment: What do you mean? it's already `#include "A.h"` in `main.cpp`, but GCC includes `inc/A.h` since it searches in `inc` before searching in `.`

Comment: I mean,remove all `-I` options and just include specific file in your source code. When you need header from `inc`, do `#include <inc/A.h>`. When you need header from current dir, use `#include <A.h>`

Comment: I see, however this behavior is causing errors when compiling a third party library that I can't modify. And there really seems to be something wrong with the behavior of GCC

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This behavior is strange: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html

Comment: I'd say it works as intended. Note the warning `ignoring duplicate directory "."
  as it is a non-system directory that duplicates a system directory`. Current dir (`.`) is automatically added by gcc, and thus is ignored by `-I` flag. Then, it first checks user inclusion path, and only then system path. As a workaround I'd try `-I../execDir` instead of `-I.`, but I'm not sure if this will change anything.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen That's not as intended. [Doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html) says: "

There are a number of command-line options you can use to add additional directories to the search path. The most commonly-used option is -Idir, which causes dir to be searched after the current directory (for the quote form of the directive) and ahead of the standard system directories." Current dir is always first if include file is in quotes. I can't reproduce this behavior on my system.

Comment: When you make a change to one "A.h" file, do you modify all the other "A.h" files?

Comment: Did you try to remove `-I.`? Your build command gives me the output `#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 .
 inc
`. In your case these two directories are swapped

Comment: I tried to remove `-I.`, it doesn't change the order in `g++ -v`. However, when I tried to make a minimal reproducible example, `g++` manage to consider the correct file... I'll need to dig a bit more to understand why my non-minimal code fails

Comment: You could go one directory up and just `-I ./dir -I ./dir/inc`. Or create a symlink to the currect directory and trick g++ `ln -s . dir; g++ -I ./dir -I./inc`.

Comment: I updated the question with a minimal example. Note that if `main.cpp` and `a.h` are in the same directory and the `g++` is also executed from this directory, there are no errors

Comment: Can't reproduce.  `g++ (SUSE Linux) 9.1.1 20190520 [gcc-9-branch revision 271396]`.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve the issue by adding

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="/home"
```

I don't know why, but it seems that having `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` starting with a colon caused the issue (since I have several `export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH:path/to/include"` in my `.bashrc`